# Write file and execute in vim for python

Tags: python, vim

I find myself commonly doing the following in vim to save my file and then execute it to see what it returns in python:

- `: w` (write)
- `:!python file.py`
- `[enter]` (to run)
- `[enter]` (again, to return back to program)

It seems very long-winded and tedious where I'm running the program tons of times while I'm developing it. What would be a better way to do this? That is, what's the best way to continuously save and execute a python script in vim?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bvim%5D+execute

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using spacevim (https://spacevim.org). It is basically a vim distribution, which facilitates using vim as IDE. You type

```
space l r
```

for running a python program, if you have installed the python layer. It runs the actual buffer, you do not need to save every time. In addition, there is a REPL support for python and you can integrate external tools as well with the task manager.

Also there is neovim, which i have not tried yet.